# 3 last record of each customer

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of customers and requests like this:

**Table of Customers:**

```
Key | Name
----+-----------
  1 | Roberto
  2 | Thiago
  3 | Mike
```

**Table of Requests:**

```
key | Date       | Customer
----+------------+------------  
  1 | 2012-02-07 | 1   
  2 | 2012-02-08 | 2
  3 | 2012-02-09 | 1
  4 | 2012-03-07 | 1
  5 | 2012-03-08 | 3
  6 | 2012-03-09 | 2
  7 | 2012-04-07 | 3
  8 | 2012-04-08 | 1
  9 | 2012-04-09 | 3
```

I want a query that return the 3 last request of each customers.
Obs: I am using MySQL Server

The return should look this:

```
key | Date       | Customer
----+------------+-----------
  1 | 2012-02-07 | 1
  3 | 2012-02-09 | 1
  4 | 2012-03-07 | 1
  2 | 2012-02-08 | 2
  6 | 2012-03-09 | 2
  5 | 2012-03-08 | 3
  7 | 2012-04-07 | 3
  9 | 2012-04-09 | 3
```

I can't use the command 'TOP' because i am using MySQL Server, and this command just is possible in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work:

```
SELECT     req.Key,
           req.date,
           req.customer
FROM       [dbo].[Requests] req
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Customers] cust ON cust.CustomerID = req.customerID
GROUP BY   req.Key, req.date, req.customer
ORDER BY   req.date
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: thanks Satwik,

but I am using MySQL Server and isn't possible use TOP, just in SQL Server.

another suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as

```
select 
r.`key`,
r.Date,
r.customer
from Customers c
left join 
(
  select 
  r1.*
  from Requests r1
  where 
  (
    select count(*)
    from Requests r2
    where r1.customer = r2.customer
    AND r1.`key` <= r2.`key`
  ) <=3
  order by r1.Date desc
)r
on r.customer = c.`key`
order by c.`key`
```

Another way of doing it as

```
select
r.`key`,
r.Date,
r.customer
from Customers c
join Requests r on r.`Customer` = c.`key`
where
(
  select count(*) from Customers c1
  join Requests r1 on r1.`Customer` = c1.`key`
  where
  c.`key` = c1.`key`
  and r1.`key`>= r.`key`
) <=3
order by c.`key`,r.Date desc
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebe74b/20)**

Answer (score 0):

You can view this [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebe74b/7).

```
SELECT DISTINCT `key`, date, customer
FROM
(
        SELECT  MAX(r1.`key`) `key`, MAX(r1.date) date, r1.customer customer
        FROM requests r1
        GROUP BY r1.customer
    UNION
        SELECT MAX(r2.`key`) `key`, MAX(r2.date) date, r1.customer customer
        FROM requests r1
        JOIN requests r2 ON  r2.customer = r1.customer
                              AND r2.date < r1.date
        GROUP BY r1.customer
    UNION
        SELECT MAX(r3.`key`) `key`, MAX(r3.date) date, r1.customer customer
        FROM requests r1
        JOIN requests r2 ON  r2.customer = r1.customer
                              AND r2.date < r1.date
        JOIN requests r3 ON r3.customer = r2.customer
                              AND r3.date < r2.date
        GROUP BY r1.customer
) subquery
ORDER BY customer, date, `key`
```

Comment: I misinterpreted the question. I took "last" to mean "newest" or "most recent" records. I like @Abhik-Chakraborty 's answer better anyway!